# How can I use NiFi to ingest data from/to ADLS

Tags: azure-storage, apache-nifi

I would like to use NiFi to connect with ADLS. My scenario is like this: Nifi is installed and running in windows machine. Now I want to move data from my windows local directory to ADLS. I am not using any hadoop component for now. From ADLS again I want to move that data to SQL server which is in Azure too.
How can I connect windows running Nifi to ADLS? All the instruction I found configuring core-site.xml files and taking the jars to Nifi specific folder. But as I don't have Hadoop running(so I don't have core-site.xml file) in that case how I can connect Nifi to ADLS?

Can anyone please share the pointers how it can be done?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use ExecuteGroovyScript processor and the native azure lib to work with adls.

Here is a java example:

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/data-lake-store-java-upload-download-get-started/blob/master/src/main/java/com/contoso/sample/UploadDownloadApp.java

But it could be easily converted to groovy script.